# php mkdir folder for every 3 number combination

Tags: php

I want do some function mkdir folder for every 3 number combination. for example, 502341 will mkdir a new forder `502/341`, 10023049132 will mkdir a new forder `10/023/049/132` I use `number_format` and `explode`, my problem is how to check how many unit were `explode` and wright some thing like

```
if(!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0])){
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0],0777);
}

$aaa = '502341';//10023049132
$bbb = explode(',',number_format($aaa));
echo $bbb[0];
if(!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0])){
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0],0777);
}
if(!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0]. '/'.$bbb[1])){
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$bbb[0]. '/'.$bbb[1],0777);
}
...//how to check more $bbb[2], $bbb[3] or even more?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `chunk_split` and `mkdir` with `recursive` option

```
$path = __DIR__;

if (! is_writable($path))
    trigger_error("$path is not writeable");

$str = "502341";
$arr = chunk_split($str, 3, "/");
mkdir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arr, 0777, true);
                                                  ^--------- Recrusive
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for *[`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)*. Make sure to validate the input beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Use the recursive mode of mkdir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to allow the creation of nested directories

Answer (score 0):

I would use recursive folder creation. For example:

```
<?php
$aaa = "502341";
$bbb = explode(',',number_format($aaa));
print count($bbb); // prints the depth of your folder tree
mkdir(implode("/",$bbb), 0644, true); // creates recursive folder
?>
```

where 0644 would be the permissions to the folder. Set this accordingly to your needs.